# Ant call sqlplus - Incanto

Tags: sqlplus

I am in the process of automating PL/SQL database scripts for Oracle DB's by invoking SQLPlus through a jar known as Incanto.

I am starting to realize I may be alone... No one seems to be using Incanto to perform this??

I am also getting an error when I run the script below of a return code of -1073741515

```
<taskdef name="sqlplus" classname="net.sf.incanto.Sqlplus"/>

    <target name="sql">
        <sqlplus silent="false" failOnError="false" resultproperty="test">
        <![CDATA[
        prompt TEST
     ]]>
        </sqlplus>
        <echo message="${test}"/>
    </target>
```

I like the idea of Incanto due to the fact that prompted input can be parametized through property files. Is there however any alternatives or does has anyone had this error before?

Full stack trace:

```
C:\_Development\Sources\Technical\AntDB\build.xml:10: Incanto task returned erro
r code: -1073741515
        at net.sf.incanto.AbstractIncantoTask.execute(AbstractIncantoTask.java:1
15)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExe
cutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:758)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was SQLPlus was missing dependency libraries.

For instance I just downloaded the SQLClient and missed the basic libraries needed in the install.